# How to Build a Makefile Project in MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, makefile

I've been working on a Makefile project, and I'm looking for a method to build it in MSVC. I find the process of continually setting up the include and linker settings quite cumbersome, and I'm hoping there might be a more streamlined approach.

Is there a way to automate or simplify these settings when working with Makefile projects in MSVC?

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are asking us to solve. With Visual Studio, you use solution files. You tagged CMake but your question is not about CMake, which is another good solution. If you want to use Makefiles, then you must know how to write them. My suggestion is to learn how to use Visual Studio to create a new project, Then learn CMake to create a new project. Once you understand the tools, you will know which tools to select and use. Note: On Windows, CMake creates Visual Studio solution files. CMake + Visual Studio + VCPKG is a nice solution for Windows.

Comment: MSVC is usually referring to a compiler. It doesn't really make sense to build a makefile project "in" a compiler. Please clarify what you're looking for.